# Google Text-to-Speech Synthesize REST API 500 Internal Error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, xmlhttprequest, google-text-to-speech

Using Google REST API - usually getting 500 error

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I have few questions:

- Is it me using API incorrectly?
- Could such behaviour reproduce with any text? Should I add some retry logic?

I'm using a simple sentence - `With Cloud Machine Learning, your application interprets images, texts and so much more.` repeated for N times. In this particular case, it's 56 times (4928 chars) to meet the limits of the API which is 5000 chars.
Reproducing in about 50% times or more.
Not reproducing with different texts like `Lorem Ipsum` (500 chars repeated) etc.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vitalii_trinity/4q250rh3/5/) (Google TTS API Key required)

Comment: This issue has been raised on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/198383659).  We cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can follow its progress on the issue tracker and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).